# Simperium on iOS not syncing data correctly

Tags: ios, synchronization, simperium

I'm testing data synchronization on 2 iPads logged in as the same Simperium user.

- If I create an object named object1 on iPad1 it successfully synchronizes with iPad2.
- If I create an object named object2 on iPad2 it successfully synchronizes with iPad1
- If I modify object1 on iPad2 it successfully synchronizes with iPad1
- If I modify object2 on iPad1 it successfully synchronizes with iPad2
- If I modify object1 on iPad1 it DOES NOT synchronize the change with iPad2 although it does push the change to Simperium's data store
- If I modify object2 on iPad2 it DOES NOT synchronize the change with iPad1 although it does push the change to Simperium's data store

I was running Simperium 0.8.3. I just updated to Simperium 0.8.12 and the problem still exists.

What can I do to troubleshoot this issue? Is this a bug?

Comment: Hello there Victor. Simperium should handle this scenario, would it be possible to get access to the code you're using? (or perhaps a simpler / smaller PoC would just do the trick). I've been unable to repro on my end. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. I had a method that I created that added an object to Core Data and wrote nil values for any data not supplied. For example:

```
+(BOOL) addActivity:(NSNumber *)identifier item_id:(NSNumber *)item_id  {

    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = appDelegate.managedObjectContext;

    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Activity" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    Activity *a = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[entity name] inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [a setValue:identifier forKey:@"id"];
    [a setValue:item_id forKey:@"item_id"];

    // Save the context.
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![context save:&error]) {

        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);

        return NO;

    } else {

        return YES;
    }

    return NO;
}
```

Apparently SPDiffer doesn't like this since it kept on throwing errors like:

```
transform diff for a ghost member (ghost <SPGhost: 0x7fba9617dae0>, memberData {
    <data>
}) that doesn't exist (item_id): {
    o = "+";
    v = 0;
}
```

when item_id does exist, except it had a nil value written so SPDiffer couldn't tell the type. I added some if statements to my code so I don't write nil values and just ignore that field.

```
if (item_id) {
    [a setValue:item_id forKey:@"item_id"];
}
```

I hope this makes sense and helps someone else out.